# Since the indexes are same for both s and t, why is t returning NaN as the first value?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, series

The 1st value is NaN for the Series t but not for s. Why is it so even though the series have same indices.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6],index= [1,2,3,4,5,6])
t = pd.Series([2,4,6,8,10,12],index= [1,2,3,4,5,6])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[s,t],columns = ["MUL1","MUL2"])
df["MUL2"] =t

df


Output:

  MUL1     MUL2
0  1        NaN
1  2        2.0
2  3        4.0
3  4        6.0
4  5        8.0
5  6        10.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If assign `Series` with different index values are generated missing values, like in first row. For correct assign need same values in `Series` and in `DataFrame`.

Problem is `np.c_` return 2d array with no index values:

```
print (np.c_[s,t])
[[ 1  2]
 [ 2  4]
 [ 3  6]
 [ 4  8]
 [ 5 10]
 [ 6 12]]
```

So if use `DataFrame` constructor is created default `Range_Index` starting by `0`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[s,t],columns = ["MUL1","MUL2"])
print (df)
   MUL1  MUL2
0     1     2 <- first 0 index
1     2     4
2     3     6
3     4     8
4     5    10
5     6    12

print (s)
1    1 <- first 1 index
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
dtype: int64

print (t)
1     2 <- first 1 index
2     4
3     6
4     8
5    10
6    12
dtype: int64
```

If change DataFrame constructor, e.g. by dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"MUL1":s, "MUL2":t})
print (df)
   MUL1  MUL2
1     1     2 <- first 1 index
2     2     4
3     3     6
4     4     8
5     5    10
6     6    12
```

Or add `index` parameter to `DataFrame` constructor by `s` or `t` Series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[s,t],columns = ["MUL1","MUL2"], index=t.index)
print (df)
   MUL1  MUL2
1     1     2
2     2     4
3     3     6
4     4     8
5     5    10
6     6    12
```

So if assign `t`, e.g. to new column all working correct, because same indices in `df` and in `t`:

```
df["MUL3"] =t
print (df)
   MUL1  MUL2  MUL3
1     1     2     2
2     2     4     4
3     3     6     6
4     4     8     8
5     5    10    10
6     6    12    12
```